# The border won't appear around my 'CLEAR' button

Tags: css

for some reason a border around this button isn't appearing, can anyone take a look at the code and find out why?

[image: The CLEAR button]

Here is my code for the 'CLEAR' button:

```
    .reset {
         background-color: #0B0B45;
         color: #11FFEE;
         margin: 30px;
         width: 120px;
         height: 35px;
         box-shadow: 0px 3.7px 2px #278ea5;
         border: 10px;
         border-color: #11FFEE;
      `enter code here`   font-size: large;
         font-weight: 800;
```

The other buttons have this CSS:

```
.button {
justify-content: center;
 margin: 30px;
 width: 120px;
 height: 35px;
 font-size: large;
 background-color: #11FFEE;
 border: none;
 font-weight: 800;
 color: #0B0B45;
 box-shadow: 0px 3.7px 2px #278ea5;
 border-radius: 2px;
```

Comment: `border: 10px` needs to be `border-width: 10px`. You may want to combine your border styles into the shorthand: `border: 10px #11FFEE solid` - for width, color and style.

Answer (score 0):

`border` is a shorthand property for border-width, border-style, and border-color. In order to make it work correctly you may change the `border` to `border-width` or set all properties of border using a shorthand.

More information about borders: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Example solution:

```css
.reset {
    background-color: #0B0B45;
    color: #11FFEE;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 35px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3.7px 2px #278ea5;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: #11FFEE;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: 800;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing your border because you did not specify a border-style property. It is important to always specify border-style otherwise nothing will be displayed. Try "border-style: solid;" for example.